# No Longer Using WordPress, but Website is Hacked and is Pointing to a WordPress Directory

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-storage, xss, bootstrap-4

Some background is needed prior to me asking the question.

I was using a third party vendor to support my website. We gave up the keys to them and had the domain registered under their name. At that time, they were using WordPress as the build (unknown hosting site). I had the support stopped and transferred the domain to a new registrar.

I decided to have Google be my new home for hosting a website. I created a website using Bootstrap and pointed the domain to it. Now everything is working perfectly. However, just recently I got a notification from Google that the website has been hacked (XSS). The hacked portion is pointing to a WordPress directory(domain/wp-content/..), which doesn't exist in Google Cloud Storage.

I forgot to delete the WordPress site prior to migrating the website to its current status. How do I go about resolving this issue?

Comment: Is it possible to see the site and also the 'hacked portion'? It's not very clear what you have done with the new site. Is the new site just a HTML/CSS (Bootstrap) site or does it use a CMS? More details would be helpful to understand what's happened/happening.

Comment: It's not possible since it redirects to the homepage. When I remove the redirect on the registrar, it 404's. There's no CMS, just bootstrap.